# How to read from file on page load using jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

I have one webpage and a file on a server. How to read from file on every page load. I m using jsp. Is there any function available to check page load?

Comment: Do you know that you read the file at the server side?, don't you?. The HTML page (generated by the JSP) can't read the file once is loaded in the browser.

Comment: Is there any alternative way? In simple words, I just want to trigger a function on page load/reload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every page load means that you come to server every time (cache is another story).
So, jsp is loaded from the server every time and here is simple directive to include file to jsp:

```
<%@ include file="foo.html" %>
```

Keep in mind that server knows only about jsp changes but not about foo.html changes. So, if you change only foo.html server doesn't know about it. That's the reason why this approach is not common. It is used mostly for common templates and parts of all pages (like common footer) even there are other better modern techniques to do so (like CSS).

However, if you still want to use external file which constantly changes just remember that JSP is Java too and you can use whatever you do in Java (except it is not recommended - JSP should be simple viewer in MVC).
So, something like this will work:

```
<% out.write(Files.readAllBytes("foo.html")); %>
```

You can use any techniques to read file and write it to the response output.

**Addition for your comment:**
Text field is regular html. Input to it would be like this:

```
 <input name=abc value="<% out.write(Files.readAllBytes("foo.txt")); %>">
```

but, again, please consider more modern techniques like DHTML, AJAX, CSS or simple JavaScript.

Comment: You are right, but how to output the content onto text field, which is on page?

Comment: I m currently using this <input name=abc value="<% out.write(Files.readAllBytes("foo.txt")); %>"> as form request (POST Method), how do I use it for page load?

Comment: Could you, please, elaborate your goal?

Comment: I have some data in simple file, I just want to display it in textfield on page load/reload, and not on submit form request.

Comment: If you want some text in text field but not in request then simply place this text field (<input>) out of the form (<form>). That form which sends inputs to the requests. It's not textfields themselves. Suggestion - make these inputs read-only. So, user will know that changes are imposible.

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm getting this "The method readAllBytes(Path) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments 
 (String)"

Comment: That was not real code but explanation. I tried to make it readable. Here is code which should work Files.readAllBytes(new File("foo.html").toPath())